# Typo3 Templavoila Plus

Tags: typescript, typo3, typo3-8.x, templavoila

So I have this problem while upgrading from Templavoila to Templavoila Plus.

I changed all XML Files from `tx_templavoila` to `tx_templavoilaplus` as suggested [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/templavoilaplus/Migration/Index.html).

After that Templavoila+ provides some scripts for upgrading the database. But my Data could not be loaded into the Control Center:

[image: Templavoila Plus Control Center]

And when I view the site it simply sais:

> TemplaVoila Plus ERROR:
>
> Couldn't find a Data Structure set for table/row "pages:X". Please select a Data Structure and Template Object first.

When I want to edit the page I'm getting the Error:

> "#1347135546: $haystack can not be interpreted as string [(More information)](https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1347135546)
>
> InvalidArgumentException thrown in file
> /var/www/typo3/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/StringUtility.php in line 35.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Here is my System:

- PHP 7.2.16
- Typo3 8.7.24
- Templavoila+ 7.30
- Mariadb 10.1.38
- Linux: Oracle Linux Server release 7.6